# Would tiling a basement floor provide any effective moisture barrier?

Tags: basement, flooring, tile, moisture

I'm about to undertake another basement remodel. With our first, we simply stained the concrete floor. We really liked the look of it. However, it still would bring in moisture at times.

This time, I'm considering tile. Would adding tile in any way help reduce the potential of moisture migrating through the floor? Or should I just assume that grout won't be any type of blocker anyways.

What if I painted the floor with a product like Redgard first? Overkill?

I may also go with vinyl plank flooring...which I assume WOULD act as a barrier.

Comment: Tiling or planking a floor with a moisture problem will quickly lead to a floor problem. Coating the inside of a basement with moisture problems will quickly reveal that water pressure almost always exceeds film adhesion strength.

Comment: Moisture would definitely seep through grout and you would likely get mineral stains on it over time as ground water wicks up through it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal no real moisture pressure to speak of, though we do need to spend some time. I'm just assuming that any concrete surface below ground will let moisture through on some level.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your location, basements will emit moisture in some degree or another. The concrete floor may appear dry, but moisture does pass through it and into the room. A tile floor probably wouldn't prevent moisture from reaching the room due to the grout joints. I've heard about heavy duty concrete sealers, but that would prevent bonding of the thinset when its time to tile. I've had very good success installing treated sleepers on top of plastic covered by plywood.

Comment: That's likely what I'll end up doing. Is there any concern about what lies under the plastic? Or is it a matter of "doesn't matter, it's under the plastic"?

Comment: I'm not sure what  "what lies under the plastic" refers to. You should sweep the floor of any large debris so it doesn't interfere with the sleepers . Maybe a quick vacuum is in order so if moisture does accumulate it doesn't muck-up anything, but other than that make sure to overlap the plastic at least 6-8 inches. It would be wise to tape them closed with a duct-like tape. Have a 'course of action'  ready if and when water has to be removed (i.e. a sump for a pump).